# Laravel relationship inactive parent

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables `posts` and `post_translations` in my `posts` table there is boolean column named `active` I want prevent child rows in `post_translations` of being visible if parent `post` active is false.

```
$post = PostTranslate::whereSlug($slug)->with(['post'=> function($q) {
  $q->where('active', true);
}])->first();
```

Code above only prevent post (parent) of being include translation results if it's inactive but it does not prevent translation itself.

**Logic**

What I'm seeking here is,

If parent (post) is inactive do not show any of the childs (post_translations) otherwise translations can be available on requests.

**Any suggestions for fixing my query?**

## Update

I managed to make it work with sql query but I will not close this question because I'm seeking for model based solution, anyhow here is how it work currently

```
$post = DB::table('post_translates')
        ->where('post_translates.slug', $slug)
        ->join('posts', 'posts.id', 'post_translates.post_id')
        ->where('posts.active', true)
        ->first();
```

Comment: try using `whereHas()` and then in closure use `where('active', true)`

Comment: It says `Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$post = PostTranslate::with('post')->whereSlug($slug)
->whereHas('post',function($q){
  $q->where('active', true);
})->first();
```